# Struggling in drawing a path graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-styles

As a beginner learning TikZ, I've tried the following:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [draw=black,
node distance = 3cm, 
on grid, 
auto,
every loop/.style={stealth-}]

\node (e1) [state] {$E$};
\node (c1) [state, right = of e1] {$C$};
\node (a1) [state, right = of c1] {$A$};
\node (t1) [state, below = of c1] {$T1$};
\node (a2) [state, right = of a1] {$A$};
\node (c2) [state, right = of a2] {$C$};
\node (e2) [state, right = of c2] {$E$};    
\node (t2) [state, below = of c2] {$T2$};

% Arrows
\path [-stealth, thick]
(e1) edge node {$e^2$}   (t1)
(c1) edge node {$c^2$}   (t1)
(a1) edge node {$h^2$}   (t1)
(e1) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(c1) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(a1) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(e2) edge node {$e^2$}   (t2)
(c2) edge node {$c^2$}   (t2)
(a2) edge node {$h^2$}   (t2)
(e2) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(c2) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(a2) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(a1) edge [bend left]  node {1}(a2)
(c1) edge [bend left]  node {1}(c2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the current result:

[image]

Improvements needed:

1. Change the two bending paths to ones with bidirectional arrows;
2. Raise the longer bending path a little higher to avoid the overlapping;
3. Change the two nodes T1 and T2 at the bottom from circle to rectangle;
4. Horizontally align those six labels (e^2, c^2, h^2, ...).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the TikZ manual on the library `automata`? Cam you share what you tried up till now in a MWE?

Comment: Please show where exactly you are struggling and show some [code to start with](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @alchemist Just added the code I have tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

[image: automata with improvements]

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678743/struggling-in-drawing-a-path-graph-in-tikz

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [draw=black,
node distance = 3cm, 
on grid, 
auto,
every loop/.style={stealth-},
myrect/.style={rectangle,draw,inner sep=8pt}]

\node (e1) [state] {$E$};
\node (c1) [state, right = of e1] {$C$};
\node (a1) [state, right = of c1] {$A$};
\node (t1) [myrect, below = of c1] {$T1$};
\node (a2) [state, right = of a1] {$A$};
\node (c2) [state, right = of a2] {$C$};
\node (e2) [state, right = of c2] {$E$};    
\node (t2) [myrect, below = of c2] {$T2$};

% Arrows
\path [-stealth, thick]
(e1) edge node[midway,right=3pt] {$e^2$}   (t1)
(c1) edge node[midway,right] {$c^2$}   (t1)
(a1) edge node[midway,right] {$h^2$}   (t1)
(e1) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(c1) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(a1) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(e2) edge node[midway,right] {$e^2$}   (t2)
(c2) edge node[midway,right] {$c^2$}   (t2)
(a2) edge node[midway,right=2pt] {$h^2$}   (t2)
(e2) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(c2) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(a2) edge [loop above]  node {1}()
(a1) edge [<->,bend left]  node {1}(a2)
(c1) edge [<->,bend left=50]  node {1}(c2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! How to change the two bottom nodes from circle to rectangle?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot and then just edited my answer.

Comment: Note that you could have created your line of nodes with a chain (using `on chain` option). Your code could be simplified a bit with this and that.